# How to model conditional summation (like sumif in Excel) in CP-SAT?

Tags: optimization, or-tools, sat, cp-sat

I am trying to model a variant of Job Shop problem in CP-SAT. In this problem, the machines have capacities >=1 so I can NOT directly use AddNoOverlap constraint from CP-SAT.

The decision variables are START and FINISH times of job operations on machines.

I want to ensure that at any given time T on machine M, the number of active operations should be <= capacity at that time.

I am new to Constraint Programming field. Please guide me in how to use the most efficient way to model in Google CP-SAT solver.